# How do I group the nodes in a force directed graph

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

I have a fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/npmarkunda/pqobc0zv/

How do I show nodes according to the group they belong to.

What is a "group"? Why do edges have both a "source" and a "target" - and what are these values? Why do links have a "value"? Aren't the links just unweighted edges? I'm having trouble understand the JSON structure of data storage.

And also how to render text as text and not as an SVG.

```js
var graph;
    function myGraph() {

        // Add and remove elements on the graph object
        this.addNode = function (id) {
            nodes.push({"id": id});
            update();
        };

        this.removeNode = function (id) {
            var i = 0;
            var n = findNode(id);
            while (i < links.length) {
                if ((links[i]['source'] == n) || (links[i]['target'] == n)) {
                    links.splice(i, 1);
                }
                else i++;
            }
            nodes.splice(findNodeIndex(id), 1);
            update();
        };

        this.removeLink = function (source, target) {
            for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
                if (links[i].source.id == source && links[i].target.id == target) {
                    links.splice(i, 1);
                    break;
                }
            }
            update();
        };

        this.removeallLinks = function () {
            links.splice(0, links.length);
            update();
        };

        this.removeAllNodes = function () {
            nodes.splice(0, links.length);
            update();
        };

        this.addLink = function (source, target, value) {
            links.push({"source": findNode(source), "target": findNode(target), "value": value});
            update();
        };

        var findNode = function (id) {
            for (var i in nodes) {
                if (nodes[i]["id"] === id) return nodes[i];
            }
            ;
        };

        var findNodeIndex = function (id) {
            for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
                if (nodes[i].id == id) {
                    return i;
                }
            }
            ;
        };

        // set up the D3 visualisation in the specified element
        var w = 600,
                h = 650;

        var color = d3.scale.category10();

        var vis = d3.select("body")
                .append("svg:svg")
                .attr("width", w)
                .attr("height", h)
                .attr("id", "svg")
                .attr("pointer-events", "all")
                .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + w + " " + h)
                .attr("perserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMid")
                .append('svg:g');

        var force = d3.layout.force();

        var nodes = force.nodes(),
                links = force.links();

        var update = function () {
            var link = vis.selectAll("line")
                    .data(links, function (d) {
                        return d.source.id + "-" + d.target.id;
                    });

            link.enter().append("line")
                    .attr("id", function (d) {
                        return d.source.id + "-" + d.target.id;
                    })
                    .attr("stroke-width", function (d) {
                        return d.value / 10;
                    })
                    .attr("class", "link");
            link.append("title")
                    .text(function (d) {
                        return d.value;
                    });
            link.exit().remove();

            var node = vis.selectAll("g.node")
                    .data(nodes, function (d) {
                        return d.id;
                    });

            var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
                    .attr("class", "node")
                    .call(force.drag);

            nodeEnter.append("svg:circle")
                    .attr("r", 12)
                    .attr("id", function (d) {
                        return "Node;" + d.id;
                    })
                    .attr("class", "nodeStrokeClass")
                    .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.id); });

            nodeEnter.append("svg:text")
                    .attr("class", "textClass")
                    .attr("x", 14)
                    .attr("y", ".31em")
                    .text(function (d) {
                        return d.id;
                    });

            node.exit().remove();

            force.on("tick", function () {

                node.attr("transform", function (d) {
                    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
                });

                link.attr("x1", function (d) {
                    return d.source.x;
                })
                        .attr("y1", function (d) {
                            return d.source.y;
                        })
                        .attr("x2", function (d) {
                            return d.target.x;
                        })
                        .attr("y2", function (d) {
                            return d.target.y;
                        });
            });

            // Restart the force layout.
            force
                    .gravity(.01)
                    .charge(-80000)
                    .friction(0)
                    .linkDistance( function(d) { return d.value * 10 } )
                    .size([w, h])
                    .start();
        };


        // Make it all go
        update();
    }

    function drawGraph() {

        graph = new myGraph("#svgdiv");
        graph.addNode('Sophia');
        graph.addNode('Daniel');
        graph.addNode('Ryan');
        graph.addNode('Lila');
        graph.addNode('Suzie');
        graph.addNode('Riley');
        graph.addNode('Grace');
        graph.addNode('Dylan');
        graph.addNode('Mason');
        graph.addNode('Emma');
        graph.addNode('Alex');
        graph.addLink('Alex', 'Ryan', '20');
        graph.addLink('Sophia', 'Ryan', '20');
        graph.addLink('Daniel', 'Ryan', '20');
        graph.addLink('Ryan', 'Lila', '30');
        graph.addLink('Lila', 'Suzie', '20');
        graph.addLink('Suzie', 'Riley', '10');
        graph.addLink('Suzie', 'Grace', '30');
        graph.addLink('Grace', 'Dylan', '10');
        graph.addLink('Dylan', 'Mason', '20');
        graph.addLink('Dylan', 'Emma', '20');
        graph.addLink('Emma', 'Mason', '10');
        graph.addLink('Grace', 'Daniel', '5');
        graph.addLink('Alex', 'Mason', '35');
        keepNodesOnTop();

        // callback for the changes in the network
        var step = -1;
        function nextval()
        {
            step++;
            return 2000 + (1500*step); // initial time, wait time
        }
   
    }

    drawGraph();

    // because of the way the network is created, nodes are created first, and links second,
    // so the lines were on top of the nodes, this just reorders the DOM to put the svg:g on top
    function keepNodesOnTop() {
        $(".nodeStrokeClass").each(function( index ) {
            var gnode = this.parentNode;
            gnode.parentNode.appendChild(gnode);
        });
    }
    function addNodes() {
        d3.select("svg")
                .remove();
         drawGraph();
    }
```

```css
.link {
            stroke: #999;
            stroke-width: 1px;
        }

        .node {
            stroke: #999;
            stroke-width: 1px;
        }
        .textClass {
            stroke: #555;
            font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Droid Sans", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-weight: normal;
            font-size: 14px;
        }
```

```html
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="addNodes()">Restart Animation</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

D3js has a  `linkDistance` option which allows for setting the distance between two nodes depending on the value.

For my example, I had to set this `linkDistance(function(d) { return  (d.value); })`

Answer (score 0):

[D3 Force Layout : How to force a group of node to stay in a given area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40941524/d3-force-layout-how-to-force-a-group-of-node-to-stay-in-a-given-area)

The links are the connections between the nodes. The source and target values for the links specify which direction the arrow should point. The length or distance, or whatever custom attributes you add to the link JSON object is usually used to specify "desired" linkDistance, though you can also specify a weight to use with the gravity setting.

Answer (score 0):

I use separate forcePoints to cluster my nodes in specific locations, it involves an extra array of X and Y values for each group

```
var forcePoint = [
"1":{"x":"200", "y":"400"},
"2":{"x":"300", "y":"600"},
];//etc.
```

Then I position the nodes around the forcePoint assigned to a location attribute in the data. In this instance, nodes with location 1 cluster to 200,400 on the SVG, nodes with location 2 cluster to 300,600. The actual array is created during a previous step of the simulation, But you get the idea.

```
var position = d3.forceSimulation(nodes)
.force('x', d3.forceX((d)=>forcePoint[d.location][0].cx)
.strength(0.8))
.force('y', d3.forceY((d)=>forcePoint[d.location][1].cy)
.strength(0.8))
.force("collide", d3.forceCollide(R * 2));
position.nodes(graph.cells).on('tick', function() {
    nodes.attr('transform', (d)=>{
    return 'translate(' + (d.x) + ',' + (d.y) + ')';
   });
```

You could also link them all to a central node within the group.