# d3/d3cola set node position, neural network drawing [Javascript]

Tags: javascript, d3.js, neural-network, webcola

The problem I have is, when drawing a neural network, I'm just sending nodes and connecting them to sensors/neurons/actuators but I never have controll on where they are being drawed.

An example of a NN I'm drawing is:
[image]

What I want to do with d3 or d3cola is, drawing on the left side of the screen the TBS_GET_INPUT which is the sensor and on the right the TBS_SEND_OUTPUT which is the actuator, so I can draw the neural network in a way it's similar to current NN drawings for example:
[image]

I attempted settings graphs.constraints but couldn't do much.
Has anyone got an idea of how to do it? How to set the constraints correctly or soemthing like that?

Regards!

Comment: Drop the force layout and use point scales instead.

Comment: By this you mean setting the position of all nodes (x, y)?
If it does, I don't want to do that since I don't have the neurons/nodes separated by hidden layers and it'd be a mess!

Comment: No, it won't be a mess, because you can create the scales dynamically, separating everything evenly.

Comment: Ok, I get you about the dynamic creation of scales, but because of the way I have the nodes information I'll never know in which layer a node will be in, what I can try is rendering nodes in the middle (I won't care were, just in between sensor & actuator) and the sensor on the left and actuator on the right.

Comment: In that case, use `forceX`. Have a look at my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40943217/5768908

Comment: I forgot to mention I'm using d3 v3 because of d3cola, and I can't use forceSimulation

Comment: I see. It's a good idea saying that in your question. Good luck to you!

Comment: Hahaha wait! I'm sure I can use that example on your answer and implement it, thanks for the help mate!